# I have high CPU and low GPU usage when training a model. I installed CUDA and tensorflow-gpu

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I have a low GPU and a high CPU usage on MNIST dataset with this model. I installed CUDA for the GPU, but nothing has changed. Can you help me?
[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7zIa.png)
[Training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7Kmw.png)

Comment: Can you post your code in the question rather than just pictures?

Comment: I can post the whole jupyter notebook as a photo if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

tensorflow-gpu requires CUDNN, in addition to CUDA. CUDNN requires a developer account and download it from https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn,

You can refer to the below page,

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

and install CUDNN and set required paths, depending on your OS as described.

If that does not help, you should post the output log (terminal) of launching your training script.